# AIR 3 Download mp3

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I want to download mp3 file, on mobile device iOs or android, because i dont want to download every time from server.
I write simple code, but not work correctly. File size is too big, because is not encode and after save I cant play it again.

Please help and sorry for bad English.

```
private var sound:Sound;
        public function loadSound(tmpUrl:String):void
        {
            sound = new Sound();

            sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadSuccessSound, false, 0, true);
            sound.load(new URLRequest(tmpUrl));
        }
        protected function onLoadSuccessSound(event:Event):void
        {
            var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            sound.extract(fileData, sound.bytesTotal);

            var file:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory + "\\ppp.mp3");
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

            fs.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length);
            fs.close();
        }
```

Comment: I think where you do sound.extract it's decompressing the mp3 into the "raw" audio wave data which means it's the decompressed/decoded version of the mp3.  My guess is you would want to just use a Loader or something like that to get the mp3 by itself.  I assume you could download the file using a Loader then use an instance of the Sound class to load that local file and play it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically answer is to use URLStream and FileStream.

Question is pretty widespread and covered, for example, here [Download a file with Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342994/download-a-file-with-adobe-air) and [AS3: URLStream saving files to desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614199/as3-urlstream-saving-files-to-desktop)